# How to get count for each type of record in a result set

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a SQL query that produces a result set as shown below:

```
(SELECT dv.venue as venue, pglr.users_oauth_uid as user_id, pgl.date as guest_list_date
    FROM promoters_guest_lists pgl
    JOIN users_promoters_guest_list_authorizations upgla 
    ON pgl.users_promoters_guest_list_authorizations_id = upgla.id
    JOIN promoters_guest_lists_reservations pglr
    ON pgl.id = pglr.promoters_guest_lists_id
    JOIN promoters_venues pv
    ON pv.id = upgla.promoters_venues_id
    JOIN data_venues dv
    ON dv.id = pv.venue_id
    WHERE upgla.deactivated = 0)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT dv.venue as venue, pglre.oauth_uid as user_id, pgl.date as guest_list_date
    FROM promoters_guest_lists pgl
    JOIN users_promoters_guest_list_authorizations upgla 
    ON pgl.users_promoters_guest_list_authorizations_id = upgla.id
    JOIN promoters_guest_lists_reservations pglr
    ON pgl.id = pglr.promoters_guest_lists_id
    JOIN promoters_guest_lists_reservations_entourages pglre
    ON pglr.id = pglre.promoters_guest_lists_reservations_id
    JOIN promoters_venues pv
    ON pv.id = upgla.promoters_venues_id
    JOIN data_venues dv
    ON dv.id = pv.venue_id
    WHERE upgla.deactivated = 0)
    ORDER BY 1

Estate  504405294   2011-08-30
Estate  504405294   2011-09-20
Estate  504405294   2011-09-19
Estate  504677586   2011-08-30
Estate  100002624783324 2011-08-30
Estate  100002624783324 2011-09-20
Estate  1451950133  2011-09-19
Estate  1634269784  2011-09-19
Estate  100002624783324 2011-09-19
Royale  504405294   2011-08-28
Royale  504405294   2011-09-04
Royale  100002624783324 2011-08-28
Royale  1634269784  2011-09-04
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to return simple counts of all the records that equal a certain value in the first column, for every value in the first column. In total I anticipate 6 unique values in the first column, but it can vary between query executions.

Comment: Isn't this the reason for the 'group by' SQL statement?  As in: "add GROUP BY dv.venue to the end of your SQL statement, and change the select portion of the statement to 'dv.venue, count(*)' ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a count of all the records in the first column for each unique value in the first column as my final result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT venue, COUNT(*) FROM (YOUR_QUERY_HERE) t GROUP BY t.venue;
```

that's all.